# Is there a possibility to get different result between Jetson nano and Desktop machine with using same Darknet weight and config?

Tags: object-detection, darknet, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am facing this problem.

I train to use darknet on my ubuntu desktop machine.
And I detect objects with the weight of the training result on desktop and jetson nano.

The result from the desktop machine with a web camera is this.
This is what I expected result to detect a Lego brick.
[image]

And this is from Jetson nano that is not an expected result.
This image shows full of tags even if there is no Lego brick in front of a camera.
[image]

When I got these results, I suspected to make a mistake to send files from Desktop to Jetson nano.
But the sending is completed correctly.
So I suspect the possibility of this post title.

I hope someone to give me some suggestions.
Thank you.

Desktop GPU: Nvidia Geforce RXT 2080 Super

Answer (score 0):

the answer is most definitely yes. what is the spec of the two cameras? are they producing images with the same number of pixels?

Comment: I used the same camera. 
I give you the additional information that Yolov4, not yolov4-tiny, performs correctly in the exact same settings of Jetson Nano.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Yolov4-tiny, I started to use Yolov4 for Jetson Nano.
Because Yolov4 performs correctly.
I am not sure the reason why though.

To avoid getting a slow frame rate, I use a lower number for the width and height in the config file.

My config file has the numbers like this.
Someone may change the numbers to balance the frame rate and the result of the detection.

```
width=288
height=288
```